# Apple Airport - Access DHCP from ethernet connection?

Tags: network, airport, ethernet

Is it possible to have a device connected to an Airport Express *via the ethernet cable* to access the DHCP / sit within the NAT functionality for Internet use?

I have an existing network where a network switch connects to both the cable modem and the Airport Express. This currently works.

I am now trying to add a wired device (an XBox 360) to the switch. All attempts to sit within the Airport's subnet have failed (manual IP setup, tested with various pings, etc). This leads me to the conclusion that all devices receiving DHCP/NAT connectivity must be wirelessly connected.

As the Airport is bridging the connection to the (internet) router, I'd like the XBox sitting within the router. The cable modem has a static IP, which doesn't share well with both the Aiport + XBox trying to use the Internet.

*Is there a way to to allow a device connected via ethernet within the subnet / DHCP-controlled zone?*

The alternative is to replace it with a wireless router with a built-in switch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The DHCP works fine for the airport.

If you use ethernet and a static IP address, then you'll have to choose an IP address outside of the DHCP lease range otherwise you can get IP address conflicts.

For example, if your DHCP range is set to 192.168.0.10 through 192.168.0.20 then you can use the IP address ranges 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.9 and 192.168.0.21 - 192.168.0.253 for statically assigned IP address.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. Is there any way you can fix the typos and make your answer more legible? This would be nice!

Comment: Ital, have you tried this? Like the OP, I have a cable modem connected to a switch, and the switch is connected to the Airport Express. Works. But when I try to connect a wired device to the switch, it does not receive an IP address. I can also not ping the Airport Express when setting a static IP.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Connect your switch to your airport, then your airport to your modem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the wording of this question. But the Airport Express has two ethernet ports, one you'd connect to the "source" of your internet, your modem or whatever. The other is a standard network ethernet port. It gets the same exact services as wifi, but faster. You can easily plug in an un-managed switch to it, and have an array of fully functional ethernet ports. You can skip the switch and plug your xBox directly into this port and it should connect right up to the internet using DHCP, as long as DHCP is enabled in the airport.

Static IPs should work too, over wifi or ethernet. They have to be correct though, in the correct range with the right subnet and good DNS. I'd stick to DHCP though. You can create "static" IPs through the DHCP in the Airport which is a nice feature that makes it super easy to setup, if you happen to need a static LAN IP.

Having re-read your question, the key here is the Airport goes **between** the modem and the switch. The switch does not connect directly to the modem.